# Get custom taxonomy terms from archive or category page

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have an archive page using both a custom taxonomy ('location') and a category the URL looks like this:

/location/scotland/east-lothian/category/animals-nature-and-wildlife/

Using get_queried_object() will return the category.

How do I get the location ie Scotland, East-Lothian?

Answer (score 0):

```
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'location' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$location = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
                    
echo $location->term_id;
```